# Determinantal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

It is well known in literature about the determinantal  varieties, symmetric determinantal varities, skew-symmetric determinantal varieties. Is it possible to study determinantal varieties over the set of hermitian matrices? Is there any study about the hermitian determinantal varieties? I have no idea about the geometry so, it may be a non sense question. If it is the case, I am sorry for that in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in this answer : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318968/dimension-of-hermitian-rank-at-most-k-matrices-over-quaternions/319011#319011 where the slightly more difficult case of hermitian matrices with quaternionic coefficients is dealt with.